# Async dispatch in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-tookit for state.

My action:

```
const updateSomething = (data: string) => async (dispatch) => {
   await user.set({ data })
   dispatch(updatedData(data))
}
```

In my view I want to do something like:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
await dispatch(updateSomething('Hi!'))
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? `updateSomething` appears to be a valid Redux thunk, so yes, you can dispatch it exactly as you've shown.  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: `updateSomething` is a valid thunk, but it does not return a promise.

Comment: The thunk function is defined as `async`, so it _will_ automatically return a promise. I'm afraid I still don't know what the actual question is here. Your example `usage` doesn't have any promise usage in it.  What are you trying to do, and what specifically isn't working?

Comment: I think the question is about dispatching the action asyncronously. is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

### Update 5 July 2021

###### TL;DR

If `typeof store.dispatch` still doesn't give you the right typing with `ThunkDispatch` as one of the overloaded options, you may consider manually typing it, like so: -

```js
export type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<AppState, null | undefined, AnyAction> &
  Dispatch<AnyAction>;
```

*Note: This is the correct typing with the default middleware, if you have added more middlewares you should try to figure out the possibilities.*

###### Background

While my proposed solution (below) works in codesandbox, it doesn't work in my project, which I ported from vanilla redux to redux toolkit. Maybe some of the packages installed break the types, just a speculation but when I include `redux-debounced` in my codesandbox sample (link below), the type for `store.dispatch` is falled back to `Dispatch<AnyAction>`, even without including `redux-debounced` in middleware.

This is certainly a mystery that has to be resolved!!

---

I had the similar issue as TS, so I made a simple project in codesandbox and surprisingly it works with a minor tweak!

In my view, what TS meant is that `updateSomething('Hi!')` is a valid thunk created using `createAsyncThunk()` in redux toolkit, where dispatching the thunk should return a `Promise`. That's a feature in redux toolkit. But unfortunately, somehow typescript is returning `AsyncThunkAction` and invoking the following line:

```js
await dispatch(updateSomething('Hi!'));
```

actually yields a typing error. Here's what I got in my codesandbox project:

[image]

In my case, `fetchDynamicName()` is a valid thunk and supposedly the type of `dispatchReturn` should be a `Promise`.

With a minor tweak found in [this post](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-usedispatch-hook), it actually works!!

All we need is to export the dispatch type of the store, like so:

```js
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

and assign the type to the dispatch function before using it:

```js
const dispatch: AppDispath = useDispatch();
```

And voilà! See the screenshot below:

[image]

You can take a look at my codesandbox project at https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-cdn-08vpu?file=/src/App.tsx.